# Kotlin: Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'String?' and 'Char.Companion'

Tags: kotlin

In this Hangman game how can I give the condition to check if input !=Char? It says that Kotlin: `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'String?' and 'Char.Companion'`

How can I solve this issue?

```
        while (letters != correctGuesses) {
            printExploredWord(word, correctGuesses)
            println("\n#Wrong guesses: $fails\n\n")
    
            print("Guess letter:")
            val input = readLine()
    
            if (input == null) {
                continue
            } else if (input.length != 1) {
                println("Please enter one letter")
                continue
            } else if (input != Char) {
                println("Please enter a character")
            }
            if (word.toLowerCase().contains(input.toLowerCase())) {
                correctGuesses.add(input[0].toLowerCase())
            } else {
                ++fails
            }
```

Comment: What does that even mean?  Under what conditions do you imagine that `input != Char` should be true?

Comment: If I enter a number instead of a character.

Comment: Strings contain only Chars.  Numeric digits, punctuation, etc., are all characters.  You seem to want to restrict the input to *alphabetic* characters.  `if (!input[0].isLetter())`

Answer (score 2):

Sounds from your comments that what you want to check is if the input `String?` has a single **alphabetic** character. You need to be precise with your terminology. Numbers and punctuation are also made up of characters. `Char` is a class representing *any* element of a `String`, so it doesn't make sense to be asking if something in a String is a `Char` because the answer is true no matter what.

The question you need to be asking is whether the first character in the given String is a *letter*. There's a function for that: `Char.isLetter()`. And since we're checking the content of the first character of the String, we need to get its value with `input[0]` because it doesn't make sense to ask if a whole String is a letter character. A String is never a Char because these are different classes. So in your case you would use:

```
if (input == null) {
    continue
} else if (input.length != 1) {
    println("Please enter one letter")
    continue
} else if (!input[0].isLetter()) {
    println("Please enter a character")
    continue
}
```

But again, the terminology is wrong here. You should be reminding the user to enter a letter, not a character.

Answer (score 0):

Your input variable is a type String?, so there's no reason to check if it's a char or not. To check for instanceof in Kotlin you use the "is" operator. So to compare if your input is a Char you can do,

```
else if(!(input is Char)) {
   //This is unnecessary though since you're already checking if the length of the input isn't 1
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want to do a check to ensure a user does not enter a number instead of an alphabet. How can I do that.

Comment: Can I use anything other than readLine() to ensure the users input is a character?